# Why is Laravel saying "Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[]' to data type int"

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5

I'm writing a search function in Laravel, and it throws the following error: `QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[22018]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[]' to data type int. (SQL: select * from Product where pID = [])`.

My controller reads as follows:

```
public function productSearch(Request $request){
        $searchResult;
        if($request->input('category') == 'all' ){
            $searchResult = Product::where("pCategory", "like", '%')
                ->where('pName', 'like', $request->input('search'))->get();
        }else{
            $searchResult = Product::where("pCategory", "like", $request->input('category'))
                ->where('pName', 'like', $request->input('search'))->get();
        }
        //dd($searchResult);
        return view('products',['products' => $searchResult]);
    }
```

And the model reads as follows:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Product';
    protected $primaryKey = 'pID';
    //

    public function orderDetails(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\OrderDetail','ProductID','pID');
    }

}
```

I don't understand why it keeps doing this, especially since I am not asking it to look at the ID. What is going on here?

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Product] (
    [pID]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [pName]        VARCHAR (50)   NOT NULL,
    [pBrand]       VARCHAR (20)   NOT NULL,
    [pCurrentType] VARCHAR (10)   NOT NULL,
    [pVoltage]     FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
    [pPrice]       FLOAT (53)     NOT NULL,
    [pStock]       INT            NOT NULL,
    [ImagePath]    NVARCHAR (500) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Product] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([pID] ASC)
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you don't have pCategory column in your table.

Second don't apply like clause for search when you receive all in category parameter.

```
public function productSearch(Request $request){
    $searchResult = new Product;

    if($request->has('search') && !empty($request->get('search')) && $request->get('search') !== 'all') {
        $searchResult = $searchResult->where("pName", "like", '%'.$request->get('search'));
    }

    $searchResult = $searchResult->get();
    return view('products',['products' => $searchResult]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See the int value is inserted into the database as String. I mean int variable is within single quote. You have to remove it.